# "There are at least n elements in the domain" is entailed from f is not injective and f is surjective

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

I am working within a first order language with one unary function symbol $f$ and no other nonlogical symbols.

I have written down sentences for 'f is not injective' and 'f is surjective denoted by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively.

$\alpha:\exists a \exists b(f(a)=f(b)\wedge\neg(a=b))$

$\beta:\forall a\exists b(f(b)=a)$

$\sigma_n$ is the statement "There are at least $n$ elements in the domain"

$\sigma_n:\exists x_1 \exists x_2 ... \exists x_n (\neg(x_1=x_2)\wedge\neg(x_1=x_3)\wedge...allPossiblePairs)$

**I need to show that $\alpha,\beta\models\sigma_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb{N}$**

The semantics I am using is:

$\Sigma\models\sigma$ means for all structures $M$, if $M\models\Sigma$ then $M\models\sigma$

So I need to show that if a structure makes $\alpha$ and $\beta$ true, it also makes $\sigma_n$ true. But how on earth do I introduce $n$ into the argument.

Comment: I'd say contradiction might be a pretty good approach. Assume $\exists n (\neg \sigma_n)$, and then show why this must contradict your hypotheses.

Comment: I see what your saying but even then I cant get going

Comment: Note that any structure that doesn't satisfy $\sigma_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ must be finite. From there it's just the pigeonhole principle that says a surjective function from a finite set to itself must be injective, contradicting your first hypothesis. Can you fill in the details?

Comment: Yes, thats helped, thank you. Just out of curiosity, wouldnt the contradiction still follow even if the structure were infinite. I know you cant apply the pigeonhole principle in that case but it still seems impossible to satisfy both $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: No, that only works for finite sets. Consider the function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ given by sending $2n$ to $n$ and everything else to $1$. Then $f$ is onto but not one to one

Comment: interesting. thanks again